# Messages not sending across networks (Python - sockets)

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm implementing a simple chat application whereby you can send messages between clients. It works fine if the clients are on the same network, but I am wondering how to get it to work if the clients are not on the same network. What are the extra steps required?

I've provided my code below, which works for same-network communications. `serve()` runs in it's own thread and listens for incoming messages (by calling `rcvMsg()`). When a user wants to send a message from `mainprocess` it calls `sendMsg()`.

```
class CMsgGateway(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, mainprocess, parent = None):  

        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.exiting = False
        self.mainprocess= mainprocess
        self.msgRcvd = ""
        serveThread = Thread(target=self.serve).start()

    def serve(self):

        while 1:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            self.sock.bind(("", self.mainprocess.port))
            self.sock.listen(1)   
            self.rcvMsg()

    def rcvMsg(self):
        serverSocket, info = self.sock.accept()
        while 1:
            try:            
                buf = bytearray(4000)
                view = memoryview(buf)
                bytes = serverSocket.recv_into(view, 4000)
                if bytes:
                    stx = view[0]
                    Size = view[1:3]
                    bSize = Size.tobytes()
                    nTuple = struct.unpack(">H", bSize)
                    nSize = nTuple[0]
                    message = view[0:3+nSize]
                    messageString = message.tobytes().decode("utf-8").strip()
                    self.mainprocess.msgs += "Friend: " + messageString
                    self.emit(Qt.SIGNAL("msgRcvd"))
                else:
                    break
            except socket.timeout:
                print("Socket timeout.")
                sys.stdout.flush()
                break

    def messageReceived(self):

        self.mainprocess.slotMsgRcvd(self.msgRcvd)

    def sendMsg(self, msgToSend, IP):

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 2)
        self.sock.connect((IP, self.mainprocess.port))
        self.sock.send(msgToSend.encode())
        self.sock.close()
```

The error I receive when trying to talk cross-networks is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatApp.pyw", line 74, in slotMsgSend
  File "C:\Users\me\documents\chatApp\source\msginterface.pyw", line 61, in sendMsg
    self.sock.connect((IP, self.mainprocess.port))
OSError: [WinError 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network
```

Comment: What problem does it have when they are not on the same subnet?

Comment: @stark I have added the traceback to the post

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You've added a traceback to your question which shows that the remote network is unreachable. In this case your code is acting as a client, so my original answer is not directly addressing your problem, however, the general principle is the same, i.e. the remote host can not be contacted because there is no route to the network on which the host is listening.

I think that you need to look at your local network configuration to resolve that - it's not a problem with your code. You may need to set up a route to the remote network... I'm not a Windows guy, but you can check out the [`route`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/route.mspx?mfr=true) command, possibly [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/122002) might help.

---

**Original answer**

What makes you think that it doesn't work between clients on different networks? Have you been able to test connections from a different network?

Routing messages between networks is not normally done in application layer code, it is performed with a the combination of network devices, such as routers, which are external to your application.

Because your code binds the socket to hostname `''`, your application is listening on all available interfaces on the host on which it is running. It makes no difference to the server where the client connection comes from, provided that there is a route from the client to the server.

You ask "what are the extra steps?". As far as your code is concerned there shouldn't be any. However, you might need to configure routing tables on the client and/or server, open firewall ports to allow bidirectional traffic from/to the client and server, or configure routers to direct traffic between nets. The details on how to do that is outside the scope of SO.

Comment: Ok thank you for your comments - Do l need a public IP address for the server in order to create a route between the clients?

Comment: No, you just need to run the server on a host that is accessible to the client. "Public IP address" is usually understood to mean a globally accesible IP address such as that used by a live web server. So if you have one of those on the server then you should be able to connect to it from your client - provided that a route to the public internet is in place on the local client host machine. Otherwise it is difficult to advise you without knowing the network infrastructure that you are dealing with.

Comment: You can test things out a bit with command line tools such as `ping`, `tracert`, `telnet` etc. Are you able to establish a connection from the client machine to the server with `telnet` using the values for `IP` and `self.mainprocess.port`?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will have a go at testing that out as soon as I can! I will comment here when I have done so.